# Упростить код вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Помогите пожалуйста упростить-минимизировать следующий код:

```
    add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters');
function post_redirect_by_custom_filters() {
    global $post;    
$catArray = ['ID1'];
    if (is_single($post->ID) && has_category($catArray, $post)) {
        $new_url = "https://syte.ru/?page_id=1{$post->post_name}/";  
        wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
        exit;    
}
$catArray = ['ID2'];
    if (is_single($post->ID) && has_category($catArray, $post)) {
        $new_url = "https://syte.ru/?page_id=2{$post->post_name}/";  
        wp_redirect($new_url, 301); 
        exit;
// И так сто раз
    }
}
```

Этот код делает редирект всех публикаций из категории ID1 на страницу https://syte.ru/?page_id=1 и из из категории ID2 на страницу https://syte.ru/?page_id=2
Таких редиректов с разными категориями и разными страницами более 100. Возможно-ли минимизировать код, или это есть оптимальный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters' );
function post_redirect_by_custom_filters() {
    global $post;

    // тут массив слагов или айдишников нужных категорий
    $catArray = array( 'ID1', 'ID2' );
    if ( is_single( $post->ID ) && has_category( $catArray, $post ) ) {
        $new_url = "https://syte.ru/?page_id=1{$post->post_name}/";  
        wp_safe_redirect( $new_url, 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mihdanВы не вникли в суть вопроса. В вашем случае будет редирект ВСЕХ публикаций из категорий 'ID1', 'ID2' на страницу "id=1". Я изменил код для наглядности.

Comment: По вопросу изначально было так понятно